# How do I split an ndarray based on array of indexes?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm fairly new to Python, and very new to Numpy.

So far I have an ndarray of data where is a list of lists, and I have an array of indexes.  How can I remove every row who's index is inside of the array of indexes and put that row into a new ndarray?

For example, my data looks like

```
[[1 1 1 1]
 [2 3 4 5]
 [6 7 8 9]
 [2 2 2 2]]
```

and my index array is

```
[0 2]
```

I would want two get two arrays, one of

```
[[1 1 1 1]
 [6 7 8 9]]
```

and

```
[[2 3 4 5]
 [2 2 2 2]]
```

Extended example, for clarity: 
For example, my data looks like

```
[[1 1 1 1]
 [2 3 4 5]
 [6 7 8 9]
 [2 2 2 2]
 [3 3 3 3]
 [4 4 4 4]
 [5 5 5 5]
 [6 6 6 6]
 [7 7 7 7]]
```

and my index array is

```
[0 2 3 5]
```

I would want two get two arrays, one of

```
[[1 1 1 1]
 [6 7 8 9]
 [2 2 2 2]
 [4 4 4 4]]
```

and

```
[[2 3 4 5]
 [3 3 3 3]
 [5 5 5 5]
 [6 6 6 6]
 [7 7 7 7]]
```

I have looked into numpy.take() and numpy.choose() but I could not figure it out.  Thanks!

edit: I should also add that my input data and index array are of variable length, depending on the data-sets.  I would like a solution that would work for variable sizes.

Comment: I would suggest `np.split` ;).

Comment: @seberg.  Post that as an answer (with appropriate code samples of course).  It's much nicer than the monstrosity I came up with.

Comment: @seberg I looked into split, but it didn't seem to be what I'm looking for.  I want a constant of two subarrays returned, where split returns more and more subarrays based on the number of indexes you provide.  Do I need to sort it first using the indexes and then split?

Comment: @k.schroeder31 now I am confused what does it mean constant of two subarrays? Does that mean you always want two rows? In that case I would suggest you reshape and then use take, or you could use stride tricks to do that neatly.

Comment: @seberg I mean the first subarray should include every row whos index is in the index array while the second array should include every row whos index is not in the index array.  Notice the index array included 0 and 2 so the first subarray should include the first and third row from the data.  I'm sorry if I made this unclear!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sorry, so you already have `take` and basically need the opposite of `take`, you can get that with some indexing nicely:

```
a = np.arange(16).reshape((8,2))
b = [2, 6, 7]
mask = np.ones(len(a), dtype=bool)
mask[b,] = False
x, y = a[b], a[mask] # instead of a[b] you could also do a[~mask]
print x
array([[ 4,  5],
       [12, 13],
       [14, 15]])
print y
array([[ 0,  1],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 8,  9],
       [10, 11]])
```

So you just create a boolean mask that is True wherever `b` would not select from `a`.

---

There is actually already `np.split` which handles this (its pure python code, but that should not really bother you):

```
>>> a = np.arange(16).reshape((8,2))
>>> b = [2, 6]
>>> print np.split(a, b, axis=0) # plus some extra formatting
[array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]]),
 array([[ 4,  5],
       [ 6,  7],
       [ 8,  9],
       [10, 11]]),
 array([[12, 13],
       [14, 15]])]
```

split always includes the slice from `0:b[0]` and `b[0]:`, I guess you can just slice them out of the results for simplicity. If you have regular splits of course (all the same size), you may just be better of with using `reshape`.

Note also that this returns *views*. So if you change those arrays you change the original unless you call `.copy` first.

Comment: Hi @seberg , is there a way to split an array using vectorized operations using numpy o other python package? My intention is to avoid the pure python implementation for np.split. Greetings, Chelo.